# Use the amsmath \looparrowright in a tikz-cd

Tags: amsmath, tikz-arrows, tikz-cd

I would like to render a commutative diagram involving some topological immersions; these are referred to elsewhere using `G\looparrowright B` with the arrow coming from `amsmath`.

I've had a heck of a time attempting to search for how to do this, as all my search results produce answers to the question "how do I get an arrow from a node to itself".

The M'W'E with the arrow I'd like to replace with `\looparrowright` labelled `loop`

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzcd}
    A \ar[r]        & B \\
    G \ar[u, hook]
      \ar[ur, loop] & \\
      % this arrow^ does not have the loop tail
      % instead produces an arrow from G to G.
  \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

I'm guessing something custom could be done with the decorations library but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Although it may be *used* with `amsmath`, that package doesn't define any symbols.  `\looparrowright` and friends are provided by `amssymb`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to TeX-SE! Getting these arrows in is discussed in the `tikz-cd` manual at the very end, i.e. on p. 15.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzset{% from the manual
math to/.tip={Glyph[glyph math command=rightarrow]},
loop/.tip={Glyph[glyph math command=looparrowleft, swap]},
loop'/.tip={Glyph[glyph math command=looparrowleft]},
 weird/.tip={Glyph[glyph math command=Rrightarrow, glyph length=1.5ex]},
  pi/.tip={Glyph[glyph math command=pi, glyph length=1.5ex, glyph axis=0pt]},
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzcd}
    A \ar[r]        & B \\
    G \ar[u, hook]
      \ar[ur, loop-math to] & \\
      % this arrow^ does not have the loop tail
      % instead produces an arrow from G to G.
  \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I looked right at that section, saw the pi arrows, chuckled, and shrugged, glossing right over the answer in front of me.

Comment: A follow-up. Defining the `math to` tip is not necessary, replacing `loop-math to` with `loop->` produces arrows, and doesn't have stem-edge alignment problems at strange angles.

Something the manual doesn't have (and I don't see a clear easy way to do) is how to define `loop'` analogous to `hook'`.